# is the set of matrices with trace equal equal to zero compact

Tags: metric-spaces

Is it true that the set of all matrices with trace equal to zero a connected and compact subset of the 2*2 matrices over R?

Comment: Which topology you put on the space of matrices?

Comment: The space of $n$-dimensional matrices (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) is finite-dimensional vector space, so usually one considers the topology induced by any norm (they are all equivalent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, definitely not, at least provided you use the standard topology induced by the obvious identification $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathbb{R}^4$.

The trace operator
$$\text{tr}: M_2(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$$ is linear, and so its kernel (the set of tracefree matrices) is a linear subspace of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$, and is obviously nonempty (it contains $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$). In particular, it is an unbounded (but connected) subset of a real vector space and so is not compact.

Comment: Can you explain please why it is connected@travis sir

Comment: All linear subspaces of vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are connected: By linearity they are convex, and so in particular they are path-connected. The space of tracefree, real $2 \times 2$ matrices is just a $3$-dimensional vector space in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$, so as a vector space (via a choice of basis) it's a copy of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Only if $n=1$. In general, if $n>1$ let $A=e_1 e_1^T - e_n e_n^T$, then $\operatorname{tr} A = 0$, but $\operatorname{tr} ( \lambda A) = 0$ for all $\lambda$, and
$\operatorname{sp} \{ A \}$ is not compact.